Use of scipy.linalg.cython_lapack.dgbsv in cython script
I was working into accellerating a solver for baded matrix using cython.
The base case is the following pure python code :
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.linalg.lapack import dgbsv

    # Define a banded matrix
    n = 5
    kl = 1  # number of subdiagonals
    ku = 1  # number of superdiagonals

    ldab = 2* kl + ku + 1
    # Create a banded matrix
    ab = np.zeros((ldab, n),dtype=np.double)
    ab[kl+ku, :] = [1., 2., 3, 4, 5]  # main diagonal
   
    # Define the right-hand side vector
    b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],dtype=np.double)

    # Solve the system
    lu, piv, x, info = dgbsv(kl, ku, ab, b)

    print("Solution:", x)
    print("Info:", info)

which gives the right (trivial) solution
    Solution: [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
    Info: 0

if I try to go through cython
    import numpy as np
    cimport numpy as np
    from scipy.linalg.cython_lapack cimport dgbsv

    DTYPE = np.float64
    def solve(double[:, :] HV, double[:] F, int n, int kl, int ku):
        cdef:
            int nrhs = 1
            int ldab = 2* kl + ku + 1
            int ldb = n
            int info = 0
            int[:] IPIV = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int32)

        dgbsv(&n, &kl, &ku, &nrhs, &HV[0,0], &ldab, &IPIV[0], &F[0], &ldb, &info)

        return np.asarray(F), info

    n = 5
    kl = 1  # number of subdiagonals
    ku = 1  # number of superdiagonals

    ldab = 2* kl + ku + 1
    # Create a banded matrix
    ab = np.zeros((ldab, n),dtype=np.double)
    ab[kl+ku, :] = [1., 2., 3, 4, 5]  # main diagonal
   
    # Define the right-hand side vector
    b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],dtype=np.double)

    # Solve the system
    x, info = solve(ab, b,n,kl,ku)

    print("Solution:", x)
    print("Info:", info)


I get as output the following
    Solution: [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
    Info: 1

Which means, that the element (1,1) of the U matrix is 0. I guess that the problem could be in the matrix ab; I played around a bit (wiht the placement of the diagonal) but I was not able to make it work.
Since the scipy function is also based on the  lapack function I guessed that the two input should be the same, but I am probably wrong.
Any ideas ?
